# Get the first live record on each quarter

Tags: postgresql, filter, group-by

we have a pricing table and I need to get the first live record on each quarter, the table structure is like this:

```
record_id (int)
start_date (date)
price (decimal)
live (boolean)
```

I need to be able to get the first "live" record on each quarter.

So far, I've been able to do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM start_date::TIMESTAMP) as quarter,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date::TIMESTAMP) as year,
distinct start_date,
live
FROM record_pricing rp
group by year, quarter,record_instance_uid
order by year,quarter;
```

I get this:

[image]

As you can see there are live and not live records there in the results, I just need the first live record on each Q, as highlighted in the picture above as an example.

Comment: Please post sample data (shown in image) as formatted text. Also why would the first 2 displayed rows,  (year: 2918 quarters: 3 and 4) not be in the result?

Comment: I'll try to post something here, the reason 2019 Q3 and 4 are not there is just because this particular sample didn't have data on those Q

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```html
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  year,quarter order by start_date asc) as Rank,
FROM (
SELECT  EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM start_date::TIMESTAMP) as quarter,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date::TIMESTAMP) as year,
record_instance_uid,live,start_date

FROM record_pricing rp
)Tab
where tab.Rank=1
```

Comment: Got this: WITHIN GROUP is required for ordered-set aggregate rank

Comment: I didn't get this point,  'order by start_date asc' can't help you u for your set?